# App freezes when using Firebase with Compose to navigate to a new screen

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm coding this app using Firebase and compose.
Whenever I create a new user on the app, it calls teh next screen, but it freezes and I get a Davey warming several times.

This is the Composable responsible for getting the new screen:

```
@Composable
fun HandleCreateUserResponse(createUserResponse: Response<Boolean>, onNavigateToNewCondoScreen: () -> Unit) {
    when(createUserResponse) {
        is Loading -> ProgressBarVesta()
        is Success ->
            if (createUserResponse.data) {
                onNavigateToNewCondoScreen()
            }

        is Failure -> Utils.print(createUserResponse.e)
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SignupViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCases: UserUseCases
) : ViewModel() {

    var isNameEmpty by mutableStateOf(false)
    var isEmailEmpty by mutableStateOf(false)
    var isPasswordEmpty by mutableStateOf(false)

    var createUserResponse by mutableStateOf<Response<Boolean>>(Success(false))

    fun createUser(name: String, email: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val trimmedName = name.trim { it <= ' '}.lowercase()
        val trimmedEmail = email.trim { it <= ' '}.lowercase()

        isNameEmpty = false
        isEmailEmpty = false
        isPasswordEmpty = false

        if (trimmedName.isEmpty()) {
            isNameEmpty = true
        }

        if (trimmedEmail.isEmpty()) {
            isEmailEmpty = true
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            isPasswordEmpty = true
        }

        if (isNameEmpty || isEmailEmpty || isPasswordEmpty) {
            return@launch
        }

        //TODO: Test if it works
        createUserResponse = Loading
        createUserResponse = useCases.createUser(trimmedName, trimmedEmail, password)
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
override suspend fun createUser(
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    ): Response<Boolean> = try {
        // Creates User, awaits success response then creates user to be inserted on Firestore
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
        val userFromAuth = auth.currentUser
        val id = userFromAuth!!.uid

        val user = User(
            userId = id,
            name = name,
            email = email
        )
        usersRef.document(id).set(user).await()

        Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Failure(e)
    }
```

This happens anytime I make a connection to Firebase, not only when creating an user.

If it helps, I'm doing dependency injection with Hilt and this is part of the AppModule:

```
@Provides
@Named("auth")
fun provideAuth() = Firebase.auth

@Provides
@Named("users")
fun provideUsersRef() = Firebase.firestore.collection(USERS)
```

Please help me, I've tried everything.

I hvae tried all the things i could think of, but didn't find much help online.

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors, but I get that Davey message on the console repeatedly, after that the screen is completely frozen and I can't click on anything.
I have tried following your video on Clean Architecture when working with Firebase, thank you for answering and for your videos! They have helped me a lot!

Comment: It's almost as if it is trying to render something to the screen, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to create the users using Cloud Functions. You can check this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91).